# Lost Thunderbird in dashboard 16.04

Tags: thunderbird

I have Thunderbird installed as I can launch it in Software Center. However, when I search for Thunderbird in the dash, it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried re-installing Thunderbird,but the search still failed. Shortly after posting this question, I restarted the machine and all is back to normal again.